# How should I go about posting research on an answer that is not mine on my own question?

Tags: discussion

[Post in question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/345487/what-are-the-coin-rates)

I am going to go about and do some in-game research and statistics gathering to try and test out the answer that was posted to the question. How should I go about adding said information? Should I answer my own question with the statistics and accept the answer that led me to them (assuming the stats prove the answer)? Should I not post my statistics at all? I feel that they should be posted, to show evidence for or against the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Go ahead and do the statistics and write up your own answer to your question and explain your findings. Reference the other answer when appropriate and show how the statistics support the answer or dispute the answer. In the later case I would also tell what the statistics seem to show is the correct answer.

As for accepting, accept whichever answer you feel best answers the question.